# Blogdown: Enable code folding with Clarity theme

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

As you can see in this [example site](https://themes.gohugo.io//theme/hugo-clarity/post/markdown-syntax/), hugo clarity theme has native code folding, code copying and line number. But it won't work with rmarkdown code blocks.

Code blocks in that example site are enclosed like:

> ```html 
> ## code goes here ## 
> </html>
> ```

while rmarkdown code blocks are enclosed like:

> <pre class="r"><code> 
> ## code goes here ## 
> </code>

My guess is that i should change something in `code.js` (see [here](https://github.com/chipzoller/hugo-clarity/blob/master/assets/js/code.js)) in order to get it working with rmarkdown code blocks, but i don't know what.

Ideas?

Comment: doesn't rmarkdown output to markdown in blogdown?

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk .html

Comment: I've looked in the `code.js` file [this line](https://github.com/chipzoller/hugo-clarity/blob/master/assets/js/code.js#L64) is the one used to get the syntax highlighting `code` tags, the fact that rmarkdown outputs only a `pre` its content needs to be wrapped in a `code` tag, i.e for `html` `<code class="language-html" data-lang="html" data-height="157px" style="max-height: initial;">`

Comment: I guess the language can be inferred from the pres class

Answer (score 0):

I think this will circumvent the problem, although editing the theme files is not the way to go, editing the function in line 63 is the one that selects the code blocks, that have classes and don't have the `noClass` class, editing the filter to accept those with parent nodes that have a class, then adding the className to the child and `data-lang` attribute:

```r
function codeBlocks() {
  const markedCodeBlocks = elems('code');
  const blocks = Array.from(markedCodeBlocks).filter(function(block){
    return (hasClasses(block) && !Array.from(block.classList).includes('noClass')) || hasClasses(block. parentNode);
  }).map(function(block){
    if(!hasClasses(block)){
        block.className = block.parent.ClassName;
        block.dataset.lang = block.className;
    }
    return block
  });
  return blocks;
}
```

**Edit : a better solution** would be to use [`hugodown`](https://github.com/r-lib/hugodown) which turns `.Rmd` into `.md` leaving the responsibility of generating `html` to hugo.

Comment: Did you managed to reproduce it? Didn't work here. I'm also looking at [this css file](https://github.com/chipzoller/hugo-clarity/blob/master/assets/sass/_syntax.sass). Maybe could add r, python, whatever classes in there?

Comment: @AlbersonMiranda I'd suggest using hugodown another package that basically turns rmarkdown into simple markdown this is a way better solution then changing the the files, or changing the extension to `.Rmarkdown`